# if else statement gives array

Tags: wordpress, if-statement, ninja-forms

I made this code to below. But it isn't working. Its giving an array.
Can somebody help me with this?

```
     <?php
/**
 *$fields['listcheckbox_1574292451270']
 */
$Extra_1 = $fields['listcheckbox_1574292451270'];

if ($Extra_1 == "1_1") {
    echo ("Correct");
} elseif ($Extra_1 == "2_2") {
    echo ("True");
} else {
    echo ("False");
}
?>
```

I tried to put at the last else `echo = "$1_extra";` but that gave an Array.

`$fields[listcheckbox_1574292451270]` is a checkbox with multiple options `"1_1" & "2_2"`

If this code isn't any good, can somebody help me with it?

Thanks

Comment: Does your checkbox allow only one selection? or multiple selection? And can you please attach the sample output of the $1_extra?

Comment: Its a checkbox from a ninja forms form. And it has 2 answers. And because it has multiple answers it gives an array right?

Sebo was right about the missing '

Updated the code in first post.

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't that first line be:

```
$1_extra = $fields['listcheckbox_1574292451270'];
```

I think you missed the ' when accessing that array.

Edit: just noticed a few things:

if echo `$1_extra;` outputs Array - to see the actual values of it you either need to convert the array to a string or iterate over it. For debugging array values you can use `var_dump($1_extra);` which provides more information than echo does.

After that you should also see how to access the data inside your array. You can read more about working with arrays in php here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: When I use var_dump I get this result. There is only one checkbox for $1_extra

array(1) { [0]=> string(8) "e_uren_1" }

How can I put that answer in for example "$item" ?

Comment: $item = $1_extra_array[0];
var_dump($item);

Comment: This give NULL as answer

Comment: Can somebody still help me with this?

Comment: sorry lost track of the conversation. If this prints out NULL there's nothing inside the array, make sure you stored the desired value first. If you're unsure how to do that please refer to the guide on working with arrays in php I've linked in my answer above.

Comment: I red your link. But I cant figure out how to store an array first in my script. Can you help me out?